# display 2 picker views in one controller

Tags: iphone

hi i'm designing a view, where i have to post a query to the bank. For that i take the following input .1)Contact Method : Phone, email or Post(1st Picker) .2) Contact time :Morning, Evening,Afternoon(2nd Picker) 3) Message
now when i select the first text field ie Contact Method, a picker view should display with its datasource. and when i select the contact time text field, it should display the datasource for contact time.

Please tell me how am i to do it

Answer (score 1):

you can create 3 arrays for each variant. Then, create some pointer, for example, currentArray. use this array as dataSource. so the only you have to do - change current array and call [myPicker reloadAllComponents] when your new field becomes firstResponder.